# compare data in a firebase document using == gives Protocol 'Any' as a type cannot conform to 'Equatable'

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

so I want to be able to compare the data stored in a firestore document to determine if the user has done something before. But when I use the operator`==` on `document data`, it throws me `Protocol 'Any' as a type cannot conform to 'Equatable'`

```
func showInstructions() {
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    if user != nil {
        if let email = user?.email{
            let docRef = db.collection("\(email)").document("starting test(squats)")
            docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                if let document = document, document.exists, let data = document.data(){
                    if data == ["did starting test": 0] { <- Protocol 'Any' as a type cannot conform to 'Equatable'
                        
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Document does not exist")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As the error says, you can't compare `Any` with something else since it can be of _any_ type. You need to typecast to a real type first.

Comment: what does that mean and how do i do it

Comment: You should do some research on the protocol Any and you must certainly learn how and when to cast values from only type to another. Some reading https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html#ID342 &

Comment: Cast your `data` to the expected type: `let data = document.data() as? [String: Int]`

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you need to specify the `Type` of `data`

the `Any` type is essentially telling the compiler that the variable could be anything, and the compiler is not smart enough to determine what it actually is by itself

The way around this is `casting` which is when you tell the compiler "this is a... (String, Int, Bool etc)"

in your case that would look like this

`let data = document.data() as? [String: Int]`

which is telling the compiler that data is a an `array` with a `String` key and `Int` values

note that if you use `as?` and the information you retrieved from Firestore is not what you expected, the cast will return nil instead. so you should check for that before using `data`